# How to build efficient button skins with larger hitareas than visible area

Tags: apache-flex

What I'm trying to do: build a super simple button skin (say a small circle when in up state, slightly larger circle when in over / down states) that has a larger mouse hit area than visible area. In other words, I'd like the button to look like a 5x5 circle when in up state, but transition to over state when the mouse is in a 15x15 pixel area around such circle - in order to make clicking on the button easier.

What I've done in the past is to use a transparent ellipse behind the the visible ellipse. This works nicely but seems like a waste of memory (not much, although if you start having a lot of these buttons it adds up) and rendering cycles (transparency). I thought I could avoid this by wrapping the ellipse in a group with a given size and listen to its mouse events, but somehow no mouse events seem to fire on such a group - not sure why.

I guess I'd love to know if anyone knows an efficient way to do this. Also would love to know why such a group won't fire mouse events, but I guess that's secondary. Simple code snippet below:

the application:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600">
    <s:Button x="100" y="100" skinClass="mySkin"/>
</s:Application>
```

the button skin:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:SparkSkin xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
             xmlns:fb="http://ns.adobe.com/flashbuilder/2009">

    <fx:Metadata>[HostComponent("spark.components.Button")]</fx:Metadata>
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.states.OverrideBase;


            protected function group1_rollOverHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                trace("roll over");
            }

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    <s:states>
        <s:State name="up"/>
        <s:State name="over"/>
        <s:State name="down"/>
        <s:State name="disabled"/>
    </s:states>
    <s:Group width="15" height="15" rollOver="group1_rollOverHandler(event)">
        <s:Ellipse height.up="5" height="12" width="12" width.up="5" 
                   x="0" y="0" x.up="3" y.up="3">
            <s:fill>
                <s:SolidColor color="0x222222"/>
            </s:fill>
        </s:Ellipse>
    </s:Group>
</s:SparkSkin>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't worry about the memory of an `Ellipse` inside of a `SparkSkin`. If you are that concerned about memory, you would want to roll your own `Button`

However, there are a couple of very minor performance enhancements that won't effect the implementation:

1. Use `Skin` instead of `SparkSkin`. it is lighter weight.
2. Use `Rect` for the hitarea. It is lighter weight than `Ellipse`

Comment: cool - thanks! any thoughts on why the mouse events wouldn't fire?

Comment: it's not very well documented, but the hittest is made against the graphics of the object, not the properties (height, width, ...) of the object. That's why when you inspect many skinclasses, they have an invisible rect with an id/comment `hitarea`